# Spring XML import dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

In my project there are a lot of spring xml files that import resources from other xml files, such as

in xxx.xml

```
<import resource="yyy.xml"/>
```

in yyy.xml

```
<import resource="zzz.xml"/>
```

Is there a way to visualize this import dependencies?

I understand this is done in runtime so some code might need to be written.

Comment: Visualize where and when? I can think of STS where there is such a visual feature that shows the beans from a set of configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

If you as a developer would like to see the dependencies, I recommend that you install [STS](http://spring.io/tools/sts) (Spring Tool Suite, i.e. Spring's version of Eclipse). Quoted from their web site:

> **Graphical Viewers and Editors**
>
> Want to get an overview of the bean dependencies in your Spring app? [...] Check out the graphical editors that come with the Spring Tool Suite, right in your IDE, just one click away from your configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [STS](http://spring.io/tools) (which I recommend), then you need to do the following:

- Right click on your Spring project (it has to be a Spring project)
- Go to "Spring" option, then "Beans Support"
- In the Tab called "Config Files", add your xml files to the list of "Maintain Spring bean configuration files:"
- In the same page, make sure you check "Enable support for  element in configuration files"
- Click Ok
- Open one of the xml files and in the list of Tabs you now should have one called "Beans Graph". There you can find all your beans with references to beans that are in xml files which are `<import/>`ed.
  [image: sample from STS]